# Set a background image for my window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I just wondering what I should do to apply an image as background of my tkinter window.
I want this window with a gif image in the background and a few buttons on top of it..

the error msg says: "**x.image = bg_image.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'grid'**"

do I need to import something else?
whats wrong? I dont even know if this PhotoImage code is supported by this version of python (python 3.1.1)...

```
from tkinter import*

window = Tk()
window.title("ksdasndsnadn")

bg_image = PhotoImage(file ="pic.gif")
x = Label (image = bg_image)
x.image = bg_image.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


window.geometry("600x300")
app = Application(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the `grid` method to the label that contains the image, not the image object:

```
bg_image = PhotoImage(file ="pic.gif")
x = Label (image = bg_image)
x.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: Thanks for that...
but do you know how to place the button on top of it? my buttons were pushed by the size of the picture...
thanks again